# Can't access my layout of R on a ListActivity

Tags: android, layout

I've got a Question. I have a ListActivity in which i can't access over R, my own layout that i wrote for it, what am I doing wrong.

So here's the Layout Code (list_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nofilter"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now i can't bind that Layout to my ListActivity over `setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);`
Here's some more Code about the ListActivity:

```
package de.retowaelchli.filterit.stats;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import de.retowaelchli.filterit.database.ADFilterDBAdapter;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class CreatedADFilters extends ListActivity {

    //Variablen deklaration
    private ADFilterDBAdapter mDbHelper;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);

      }  
    }
```

Wham am I doing wrong?

Best Regards

safari

NOTES:

I tried to clean my Project, it didnt work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the import of the R class is from your application and not com.android.R.
Sometimes when you use Eclipse's auto import it will import the wrong one...

Answer (score 1):

use layout file like :

```
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));
```

[This](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) is a ListActivity example.

Comment: Hello Khushbu, I tried your answer, but i still can't bind my own layout, it didnt work. :(

Comment: remove linearlayout from your xml file, write only textview with other than empty id. give your own id to TextView. you can see example from given link in answer.

Answer (score 1):

try to use LayoutInflater.

LayoutInflater mInflater;
mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth cleaning your project. If you're using eclipse, go to: Project > Clean...

Answer (score 0):

You must have one ListView in your project Layout file. And also see for delete android.R if it is auto imported there.If you are not using listview then y r u exetnding ListActivty.Extend Activity only.